# Payload for GET_FILE in Idc service in Oracle UCM

Tags: bpel, payload, oracle-ucm

I am using bpel to integrate with  Oracle UCM. I need to download a file from UCM and need to process the file with some enrichment.
For integration , I am using GET_FILE operation of Idc service. 
My xslt where I am passing params look like .

```
                <tns:GenericRequest>
                  <xsl:attribute name="webKey">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">cs</xsl:text>
       </xsl:attribute>
  <tns:Service>
    <xsl:attribute name="IdcService">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">GET_FILE</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <tns:Document>
      <tns:Field>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">dDocName</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:ADP_Params/ns1:Param1"/>
      </tns:Field>
       </tns:Document>
  </tns:Service>
</tns:GenericRequest>
```

But I am not getting expected result. My response is as follows

```
     <ns2:Service  IdcService="GET_FILE">
    <ns2:Document>
      <ns2:Field  name="StatusCode">-32</ns2:Field>
       <ns2:Field  name="refreshMonikers"/>
     <ns2:Field  name="refreshSubMonikers"/>
     <ns2:Field  name="IdcService">GET_FILE</ns2:Field>
     <ns2:Field  name="changedMonikers"/>
      <ns2:Field  name="dDocName">UCM001</ns2:Field>
      <ns2:Field  name="idcToken"/>
       <ns2:Field  name="StatusMessage">Unable to execute service    GET_FILE and function computeDocID. The error was caused by an internally generated issue. The error has been logged.</ns2:Field>
     <ns2:Field  name="IdcErrorFunction">computeDocID</ns2:Field>
      <ns2:Field  name="dUser">User1</ns2:Field>
      <ns2:Field  name="localizedForResponse">1</ns2:Field>
      <ns2:ResultSet  name="UserAttribInfo">
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If *dID* is not specified, *dDocName* and *RevisionSelectionMethod* must specified.

> Either the content item revision ID (*dID*) must be specified or a
>   Content ID (*dDocName*) along with a *RevisionSelectionMethod* parameter
>   must be defined.

So, you need to add something like RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e11011/c04_core.htm#CSSRG2458)

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of information in the log. Log into CS and go to Administration - Log files. Run your request again and look at the newest log entry. Post it here if you need more help.

/Sam